# Given a collation, how to pick the "simplest" of multiple equivalent forms?

Tags: java, unicode, collation, unicode-normalization

We are working with data that uses different spelling variants to denote the same entity.  Let's use auto makers as an example: Maybe one record says "Citroen", another "Citroën", but they mean the same French auto maker.

Now I want to find the "simplest" form of these names (here: "Citroen") to use as the main name for this auto maker and all others (here: "Citroën") will become alias names.

Even better: is there a way for me to compute the "simplest" form even if it never occurs in the data?  E.g. all records say "Citroën", but I compute "Citroen" anyway?

In this way, I could quickly determine whether new data that mentions an auto maker matches any of the auto makers I already know about: I just convert the auto maker in the new data to its simplest form, then match against all the simplest forms I know, then I can see whether I've seen this auto maker before.

Java offers a way to compare strings given a collation, so I can find out that they are equal.  But I have not found how to find the simplest form.

(Unicode normalization does something different, though I will want to apply that, as well.)

Comment: A very crude approach is to convert the string to NFD or NFKD, then strip all characters with general category "M" like combining marks.

Comment: Thank you @nwellnhof, I guess it would work well for names using the Latin alphabet.  I am, however, a bit afraid that this won't match the collation I'm given exactly.  I will have to think about it.